# Searching for tags in documentation returns nothing when searching in upper-case

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, search

I'm trying to use the tag documentation search, https://stackoverflow.com/documentation?tab=name I first tried searching for `F#` and found nothing. I then tried `f#` and after a delay it appeared. I then tried `F#` again, and quickly re-typed in `f#`. The search never came back with any results (presumably because there's a throttle on textbox change events that does a case-insensitive comparison somewhere).

I've also tried searching `.NET`, which seems to find nothing, but `.net` does seem to work.

So, it looks like it's converting tags into lower case and matching that, but not converting the search term into lower case.

Comment: Ah, that's why it wasn't working for me in Ipad. Typing in `sql` automatically gets entered as `Sql` unless explicitly changing the case of the first letter.

Comment: Looks like this is `status-completed`.